# Loop en diccionario con condición - Par k,v con múltiples valores

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hola a todos soy nuevo en Python,

Tengo el siguiente diccionario:

```
10100: {'ORDERPRICE': 5151.0,
  'ORDERDATE': '1/6/2003 0:00',
  'STATUS': 'Shipped',
  'PRODUCTLINE': 'Vintage Cars',
  'PRODUCTCODE': 'S18_1749',
  'CUSTOMERNAME': 'Online Diecast Creations Co.',
  'CITY': 'Nashua',
  'COUNTRY': 'USA'},
 10101: {'ORDERPRICE': 3782.0,
  'ORDERDATE': '1/9/2003 0:00',
  'STATUS': 'Shipped',
  'PRODUCTLINE': 'Vintage Cars',
  'PRODUCTCODE': 'S18_2325',
  'CUSTOMERNAME': 'Blauer See Auto, Co.',
  'CITY': 'Frankfurt',
  'COUNTRY': 'Germany',
 ORDERID_N: {.........}
```

Las llaves son 10100, 10101, etc. y los valores son tal que:

```
dic.values()
dict_values([{'ORDERPRICE': 5151.0, 'ORDERDATE': '1/6/2003 0:00', 'STATUS': 'Shipped', 'PRODUCTLINE': 'Vintage Cars', 'PRODUCTCODE': 'S18_1749', 'CUSTOMERNAME': 'Online Diecast Creations Co.', 'CITY': 'Nashua', 'COUNTRY': 'USA'}
```

Necesito encontrar aquellos primeros 100 elementos del diccionario que tengan por `PRODUCTLINE: Motorcycles` el problema es que no acabo de saber como iterar dentro del diccionario ya que v tiene muchos valores. He empezado con algo tal como:

```
# Recorrer los pares (k,v) del diccionario
for (k,v) in dic.items():
# Tengo que recorrer la lista de valores
for val in dic[v]:
# No sé cómo escribir la condición de PRODUCTLINE:Motorcycles
```

Si el bucle anterior está definido correctamente, no sé como definir la condición debido a la estructura de los datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inventé un tercer producto a tu ejemplo para tener algo que encontrar:

```
dicc = {
10100: {'ORDERPRICE': 5151.0,
  'ORDERDATE': '1/6/2003 0:00',
  'STATUS': 'Shipped',
  'PRODUCTLINE': 'Vintage Cars',
  'PRODUCTCODE': 'S18_1749',
  'CUSTOMERNAME': 'Online Diecast Creations Co.',
  'CITY': 'Nashua',
  'COUNTRY': 'USA'},
 10101: {'ORDERPRICE': 3782.0,
  'ORDERDATE': '1/9/2003 0:00',
  'STATUS': 'Shipped',
  'PRODUCTLINE': 'Vintage Cars',
  'PRODUCTCODE': 'S18_2325',
  'CUSTOMERNAME': 'Blauer See Auto, Co.',
  'CITY': 'Frankfurt',
  'COUNTRY': 'Germany'},
10102: {'ORDERPRICE': 5151.0,
  'ORDERDATE': '1/6/2003 0:00',
  'STATUS': 'Shipped',
  'PRODUCTLINE': 'Motorcycles',
  'PRODUCTCODE': 'S18_1749',
  'CUSTOMERNAME': 'Online Diecast Creations Co.',
  'CITY': 'Nashua',
  'COUNTRY': 'USA'},
}
```

La lista `productos` contiene las llaves de los productos encontrados

```
productos = []
```

Recorremos el diccionario de productos extrayendo llave y valor. El valor es otro diccionario, y podemos consultar por su llave `PRODUCTLINE` y compararla con la línea buscada. Si se cumple la condición, agregamos la llave del producto a la lista `productos`. Si la lista tiene ya 100 elementos, terminados el ciclo.

```
for key, value in dicc.items():
    if value['PRODUCTLINE'] == 'Motorcycles':
        productos.append(key)
        if len(productos) == 100:
            break;
```

**Demo**

```
print(productos)
```

produce:

```
[10102]
```

**Versión con comprensión de listas**

El ciclo iterativo se puede comprimir más usando comprensión de listas:

```
productos = [key for key, value in dicc.items() if value['PRODUCTLINE'] == 'Motorcycles'][:100]
print(productos)
```

La única diferencia con la versión trabajosa es que no podemos contar cuantos elementos hemos encontrado hasta el momento (podrían ser más de 100), asi que tenemos que usar rebanada de listas para tomar los 100 primeros.

**Versión con compresión sin rebanada**

Por sugerencia de Abulafia, he aquí la versión que evita generar más de 100 elementos en la lista:

```
productos = list(itertools.islice((key for key, value in dicc.items() if value['PRODUCTLINE'] == 'Motorcycles'), 100))
```

produce:

```
[10102]
```

Analicemos la expresión por partes. Primero nos llama la atención que en lugar de `[]` para producir una lista, se usan `()`. ¿Cual es la diferencia?

```
(key for key, value in dicc.items() if value['PRODUCTLINE'] == 'Motorcycles')
```

Esta expresión es un *generador*: en lugar de producir la lista completa como resultado, va entregando los elementos uno a uno, a medida que se necesitan.

Un generador encapsula un iterable. Es conveniente, pues evita tener que definir una clase e implementar el método `next`. Un generador es entonces un iterable.

La función `itertools.islice` tiene dos formatos. Aquí se ocupa la forma sencilla:

```
itertools.islice(iterable, stop)
```

Esta función es otro generador que extrae uno a uno los elementos del iterable hasta completar el número dado por `stop`.

Como es un generador, no produce una lista; tenemos que construirla usando `list`. Esta función toma un iterable, extraer todos los valores y los devuelve en una lista tradicional.

Python es maravilloso.

Comment: `productos = list(itertools.islice((key for key, value in dicc.items() if value['PRODUCTLINE'] == 'Motorcycles'), 100))` evita crear la lista larga para luego tomar 100 elementos. Se detiene en cuanto se tengan 100.